# AS3 "Type was not a compile time constant"

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok, so here's my problem. I'm decompiling an old swf trying to get it to work. I've got it almost working, but I keep having the same problem. I keep getting the following error:

com\clubpenguin\tools\localtext\core\LocalTextProxy.as, Line 84 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Font.

Here's the code:

```
    package com.clubpenguin.tools.localtext.core
    {
       import flash.text.Font;

       public class LocalTextProxy extends Object
       {

  public function LocalTextProxy() {
     super();
  }

  private static const _localTextFields:Array = [];

  private static const _fontLibraryDependants:Array = [];

  private static var _localText:ILocalText;

  private static var compileTimeEnumeratedFonts:Vector.<Font> = Vector.<Font>(Font.enumerateFonts());

  public static function queueLocalTextField(localTF:ILocalTextField) : void {
     if(!_localText)
     {
        _localTextFields.push(localTF);
     }
     else
     {
        _localText.addLocalTF(localTF);
     }
  }

  public static function queueFontLibraryDependant(dependant:IFontLibraryDependant) : void {
     if((_localText) && (_localText.libraryInitialized))
     {
        dependant.onFontLibraryLoaded();
     }
     else if(_localText)
     {
        _localText.registerFontLibraryDependant(dependant);
     }
     else
     {
        _fontLibraryDependants.push(dependant);
     }

  }

  public static function get initialized() : Boolean {
     return !(_localText == null) && (_localText.libraryInitialized);
  }

  public static function get localText() : ILocalText {
     if(!_localText)
     {
        throw new Error("An ILocalText implementation has not been set.");
     }
     else
     {
        return _localText;
     }
  }

  public static function set localText(value:ILocalText) : void {
     var localTF:LocalTextField = null;
     var fontLibDependant:IFontLibraryDependant = null;
     _localText = value;
     for each(localTF in _localTextFields)
     {
        _localText.addLocalTF(localTF);
     }
     _localTextFields.length = 0;
     for each(fontLibDependant in _fontLibraryDependants)
     {
        if(_localText.libraryInitialized)
        {
           fontLibDependant.onFontLibraryLoaded();
        }
        else
        {
           _localText.registerFontLibraryDependant(fontLibDependant);
        }
     }
     _fontLibraryDependants.length = 0;
  }

  public static function get allFonts() : Vector.<Font> {
     if(!_localText)
     {
        return compileTimeEnumeratedFonts;
     }
     return _localText.fontLibrary.allFonts;
  }
       }
    }
```

I cannot for the life of me get this error resolves. If I just remove the code, I get no other errors (except for the same error in other files), so I know this is the last thing I need to get working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It's a Flash 9 file, set to publish with ActionScript 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Has the namespace of the Font class changed?

Comment: 'flash.text.Font' is still right afaik...

Comment: I've only just started AS3, as far as I know the classes are correct.

Comment: So *which* line is 84? Identity it and remove all unrelated code from the question (that is, create a *minimal* reproduction case).

Comment: public static function get allFonts() : Vector.<Font> {
     if(!_localText)
     {
        return compileTimeEnumeratedFonts;
     }
     return _localText.fontLibrary.allFonts;
  }
       }
    }

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be a Flash 9 file, because `Vector` type was introduced in Flash 10, and is not available in Flash 9 and below. So, set compile mode to Flash 10 and try again.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did set it to 11 to no avail, but you're solution lead me to the answer. I went back to the decompiler, and overrode the settings, so it decompiled in Flash 10 no matter what. Using that .as file, I was able to get it to work! Thanks so much!